# PrestaShop - Shopping cart icon not showing

Tags: templates, prestashop, font-awesome

I have this problem in PrestaShop, I do not know what I did but now the image of my shopping cart does not work. It is written: `F291` and I have no idea why. How can I change it?

[image: Shopping cart icon missing]

I did not touch any code, just working in PrestaShop admin version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`F291` is a shortcode used with [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) to display a shopping basket icon.

FontAwesome is a custom font that has symbols/icons that replace normal text characters, it is used in many templates, including PrestaShop templates.

You can double-check it here:
https://fontawesome.com/icons/shopping-basket?style=solid

[image: FontAwesome Shopping Basket Icon]

Assuming you did not make any modifications to your template, the most probable cause is that the URL used to link the FontAwesome CSS file no longer works.

**Steps to resolve this issue:**

1. Search for *fontawesome* across all the files in your /themes/themename/ PrestaShop folder
2. Once you have found the file/line calling the FontAwesome CSS file, replace it with:
   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">`

I hope this helps.